# Montar um programa que exiba impressões digitadas pelo usuário

Tags: c

Galera, estou com dificuldade pra montar isso usando o for, eu sei como fazer um programa que exibe números pares ou ímpares até o número digitado mas como faço para que ele possa exibir quantos números o usuário informar em `num`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int op, num, x;

    printf("1.pares\n2.Impares\n");
    scanf("%d", &op);
    printf("Digite o numero de vezes que voce quer imprimir\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if (op==1) { for (x=2; num>=x; x=x+2) {
    printf("%d\n", x); }
     }else if (op==2) {
     for (x=1; num>=x; x=x+2) {
        printf("%d\n", x);
     }
    }
}
```

A ideia é o usuário escolher entre par ou ímpar e, em seguida, escolher quantos números serão apresentados (ex.: exibir 5 numeros pares, exibir 3 numeros ímpares)

Comment: Coloque ao menos o que você tentou fazer.

Comment: Não consegui entender a lógica, esse é o problema

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito o seu problema. É para fazer um programa que leia do usuário se ele quer par ou ímpar, quantas impressões e fazer exatamente o que com esses números?

Comment: Eu também não havia entendido pois o conceito é um pouco complicado, veja que no exemplo que eu coloquei ele digita os números pares ou ímpares até o número que foi digitado. Mas no caso eu queria algo como por exemplo: eu escolho pares e digito 5 e el vai digitar 2 4 6 8 10

Comment: Então a ideia é escolher entre par ou ímpar e escolher quantos numeros serão apresentados (ex.: exibir 5 numeros pares, exibir 3 numeros ímpares)